# How to inherit class from Modulename.classname in different target

Tags: ios, swift

I have created Xcode project named LearnSwift and i have duplicated the target.
So now i have 2 targets in my app: LearnSwift and LearnSwift2
In LearnSwift i have 2 files AppDelegate and ViewController.swift
I want to add one new file named TestViewController only in LearnSwift2 target
And want to inherit TestViewController from LeranSwift.ViewController.

```
import LearnSwift

class TestViewController: LearnSwift.ViewController {
.....
```

I have  marked LearnSwift target as shared. And ViewController is open to inherit.
But I am getting couple of errors with this (screenshot for the error is attached).

Can somebody help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you made the `LearnSwift` project "define a module" in its build settings?

Comment: Thanks.I did not. but i tried just now and still getting the same error. Do I need to add anything in Module Map file or any other settings?

Comment: Not sure, I'm not to familiar with this. Just trying what I can

Comment: I've never seen a linker (`ld`) error in Swift, have a +1 for novelty

Comment: Could you upload this project, or a similar test project exhibiting the same error?